# How to add milliseconds in printing the current system time as a timestamp in C?

Tags: c

I used this code below but it will print the time as HH:MM:SS without milliseconds. It works good but without milliseconds.
So how can I add milliseconds to print milliseconds to the timestamp?

my code is:

```
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
  printf ("Current local time: %s\n",asctime(timeinfo));
```

Comment: You can't use `time()` to get sub-second timing; it doesn't support it.  What you choose instead is platform specific.  On many POSIX systems, [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) is correct (it gives nanosecond resolution timing.  In practice, [`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) is even more portable (it is available on Mac OS X but `clock_gettime()` is not).  The suggested duplicate recommends [`ftime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/ftime.html).

Comment: The `ftime()` function has not been a part of POSIX for a while, but is still commonly supported.  And then there are the Windows-specific functions.

Comment: I tried clock_gettime() but it does not work, may be I wrote it in wrong way. Can anybody modify the code to make it works if possible?

Comment: The `clock_getttime()` function does work on platforms where it is available (e.g. code using it doesn't even link on Mac OS X, but it's fine on Linux), so you were probably using it incorrectly.  However, since you've not shown us how you were using it, we can't help you fix it.